# Any TCP ping with TTL

Tags: azure, cloud, ping, icmp, ttl

i'm attempting to create a project to compare pings on different datacenters of the major cloud providers. Since ICMP is blocked by the load balancer on Azure VMs i've been forced to use TCP ping instead (PsPing on Win and paping on UNIX) the only problem is that with every ping I also need the associated TTL (which is shown with the standard ping command from the bash:
[image: Ping on UNIX:]

All the different TCP ping utilities i've found(psping, paping...) doesn't provide this information, does anyone know any utility that could solve my problem?
Thank you very much in advance

UPDATE:

I've found hping3, another similar program that offers much more options and display the TTL for every ping(exactly as i wanted) anyway i noticed something  strange:
[image: Ping and hping3 from eu-west-2a to eu-west-3c]
In the image there is a test on AWS from eu-west-2a(london) to eu-west-3e(paris) and while with ping the TTL stays stable on 48 with hping3 it floats from 46 to 48 with slightly higher rtt.
I suppose the delay in the rtt it's because of the TCP overhead but i don't understand why the ttl is different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If TTL is different is because the packet is following different paths, here traceroute is your friend, hping3 has a --traceroute option that will allow seeing the different hops and spot the differences (hping3 --traceroute -S -p 80 xxxxx)

Just guessing, maybe Azure is doing something different with the traffic because it has the same pattern of a SYN flood attack.

Comment: Thank you Antonio for the tip, I've tried using --traceroute with hping3 but to be honest i'm struggling to get it to work, anyway I will investigate and see what I find ;D